# Separate integers from an string expression in snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I wanted to separate integers in a string an build an array
For example 50 + 80 in column I wanted to get [50,80] this is simple example in my column
I will have more complex expressions such as (10 + 20) / 30 I want [10,20,30]
I may have +,-,*,/,(,),' ' remove all this and wanted to build and array with comma separated numbers.

I tried replace but the output is string so my array is coming as ['10,20,30'] can we do this regexp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with `regexp_substr_all`

```
set str='(10 + 20) / 30';

select regexp_substr_all($str,'[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify your question to:

> How do I transform the string `'10,20,30'` into an array of numbers?

A quick hack to solve this is to use `parse_json()`:

```sql
with data as (select '10,20,30' x)

select parse_json('['|| x ||']')
from data
```

[image]